# Check combobox value and to discount

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my script

I want to change the combobox update when the appropriate value and check whether you discount

my js

```
function desconto(a){

    var result;

    switch(a){

            case 3: 
                result = 17;
                break;

            case 6: 
                result = 33;
                break;

            case 12:
                result = 42;
                break;

            case 24:
                result = 59;
                break;

            default:
                result = 0;
                break;
    }


    return result;


}

function tratar_valor(value,prefix){

    if(desconto(value) === 0){

       return value * prefix;

   }else{

       return (value * desconto(value)) / 100 * prefix;

   }



}

function change_value(a,b,c){
    var value    = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value; 
        document.getElementById(b).innerHTML = '€ '+ tratar_valor(value,c) ;
}


</script>
```

and my HTML

```
                    <li class="price-row">
                        <h1 id="val">€20</h1>
                        <span>
                        <select id="lol" onchange="javascript:change_value(this,'val',20)">
                        <option value="1">month</option>
                        <option value="3">3 months - 17%</option>
                        <option value="6">6 months - 33%</option>
                        <option value="12">1 year  - 42%</option>
                        <option value="24">2 years - 59%</option>
                        </select>
                        </span></li>
```

I've been watching it seems that the value is passed as default on the switch.

it is therefore not effect the appropriate discount.

I program in php and I have a very basic understanding of javascript and could not solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you parse the string from

```
var value    = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
```

as an integer, as it might be a string:

```
var value    = parseInt(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
```